# Ember how do I know when a route template is finished loading and fire a callback?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Currently working on a chat app with Ember, which is going fantastic as Ember is really nice to work with.

I currently have a chat window, obviously with many lines of people chatting.

I would like to scroll the chat window down on initial page load, here's an example:

```
<div class="chat-window">
    {{ chat-message username="John Doe" message="Blah" dispic="unknownUser.jpg" }}
</div>
```

So how might a bind an event to the entire template being loaded (in this case its `index.hbs`

I know you can do this with components through something like:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  didInsertElement() {
    this.$('.button-collapse').sideNav();
  }
});
```

Which works fine, so what would the equivalent be for doing it to a template.

As far as I know there is only the `index.hbs` and `index.js` route file.

Any information would be great thanks.

Comment: Well It was `View`, but was removed in favor of components because of inconsistent behavior. For now go with a component. In the end non-component templates will get deprecated in favor for routable components but for now the best way to go is to call a component from your route template.

Comment: I would +1 for send an action from your `didInsertElement()`

Answer (score 0):

Send an action from the component to the route. Route will retrieve data from server and after data is retrieved route will update the data.

Route can handle loading state. ([From Guide](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.5.0/routing/loading-and-error-substates/#toc_the-code-loading-code-event))

The code will be something like that:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  chatData:[],
  model:function(){
      return this.get('chatData'); 
  },
  actions:{
      loading:function(){
         //do about loading...
      },
      chatDataRequested:function(){
          retrieveData().then((dataFromServer)=>{this.set('chatData',dataFromServer);});
      }
  }
});
```